# How to solve "Cannot find module" in node js terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

After I run the node file in the VSCode terminal using (`node ./hello.js`), it shows the above error in the image.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: i tried node ./hello.js but still same error

Comment: What does `hello.js` look like?

Comment: Can you try running `npm install`?

Comment: The argument you pass to `node` needs to be a **path to a file that actually exists**. The error message just says it can't find the file you are telling it to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you created can't be found.

There can be different reasons,but...

1. check if you correctly named file and the name of the file is actually hello.js
2. check if you write path of the file correctly, maybe u saved it somewhere in the folder.